# How can I get the old GNEVE to work?

Tags: use-package, require, load

I wanted to try GNEVE, the video editor for Emacs, but its code is from 2008;)

```
(use-package gneve :ensure t)
```

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Loading file /home/b0ef/.emacs.d/straight/build/gneve/gneve.elc failed to provide feature ‘gneve’")
  require(gneve nil t)
  (not (require 'gneve nil t))
  (if (not (require 'gneve nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'gneve) :error))
  (prog1 (if (not (require 'gneve nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'gneve) :error)) (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) now)))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package gneve" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package gneve"))))
  (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package gneve") (prog1 (if (not (require 'gneve nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'gneve) :error)) (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) now)))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package gneve" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package gneve")))))
  (condition-case err (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package gneve") (prog1 (if (not (require 'gneve nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'gneve) :error)) (let ((elapsed (float-time (time-subtract ... now)))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package gneve" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package gneve"))))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning164 :catch err)))
  (progn (straight-use-package 'gneve) (defvar use-package--warning164 #'(lambda (keyword err) (let ((msg (format "%s/%s: %s" ... keyword ...))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create "*use-package*")) (goto-char (point-max)) (insert "-----\n" msg "\n\n(use-package gneve :ensure t)\n\n  -->\n\n(use-packa...") (emacs-lisp-mode)) (setq msg (concat msg " (see the *use-package* buffer)")) (display-warning 'use-package msg :error)))) (condition-case err (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package gneve") (prog1 (if (not (require 'gneve nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'gneve) :error)) (let ((elapsed (float-time ...))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package gneve" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package gneve"))))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning164 :catch err))))
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

Any forks or hacks to make it work?;)

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is apparently not how to get "the old GNEVE to work". It's about how to get `use-package` to successfully load `gneve.el[c]` and realize that the load is successful/OK.

The error message is telling you that it loaded file `gneve.el[c]`, but that file doesn't `provide` the feature `gneve`.

If you don't want to change `gneve.el` then use `load-library` or similar, instead of `require`, to load it.